# How can I automate a "conffile" prompt in unattended upgrades?

Tags: apt, updates, sudo

We have many systems, managed via Ansible. They are configured to run nightly security updates. We have a problem because the sudo package wants to put in a new `/etc/sudoers`. This is what now happens in our cron output:

```
/etc/cron.daily/apt:
Package 'sudo' has conffile prompt and needs to be upgraded manually
```

I can manually `apt-get install sudo` on a box and press the button to keep my config file, but that doesn't scale well. Is there a config I can tweak so that the nightly security updates, at least in this instance, know my preference to keep our local `/etc/sudoers`? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This appears to be the desired answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139554/5571

> I also want to keep original config files while doing automatic updates. You can add the following to /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
>
> ```
> Dpkg::Options {
>    "--force-confdef";
>    "--force-confold";
> };
> ```
>
> See here for a good explanation of the options: http://raphaelhertzog.com/2010/09/21/debian-conffile-configuration-file-managed-by-dpkg/