# Ubuntu unattended-upgrades

Tags: command-line, apt, updates

Origanally I have posted this question on stackoverflow, due to the fact it is the wrong forum. I'm asking the question again here with some extra information I have gathered.

I'm looking into creating a script in bash for automating my update-u^grade process for all my virtual machiens as a homelabber.

I'm a developer but currently not have that good knowledge of bash:

My current script is pretty simple:

```
#!/bin/sh

apt update -y
apt upgrade -y
apt autoremove -y
```

After some answers on the stackoverflow and some research on this forum I missed the `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` part So i tested with this command: `sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt upgrade -y` but still witouth good results.

The problem i'm facing is that all my virtual machines have the sh config file edited with a /etc/issue.net included since this is a standard security practice founded on every information I could gather.
Due to the fact that this file has been edited, while upgradeing the ssh-server package it asks what I want to do? Default it will take the local edited version but it requires the user to `PRESS ENTER`
When trying the command above I still had to PRESS ENTER, however after the upgrade was done I discovered in the terminal `NEEDRESTART DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive service`.

So first: Is it possible after env variable change it need a restart to take affect?
Due to the fact that the ssh package does not always have an upgrade available is there something I can do to test this?

And/or as last question Does the env variable not change the effect for the user input?
I haven't tested my script on cron tab to see if it's is working or not due to the fact again that there is not always an upgrade available.

[image: terminal]

Comment: Specifically see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/832648/1066942) on how to configure `unattended-upgrade` for different scenarios.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I automate a "conffile" prompt in unattended upgrades?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/921162/how-can-i-automate-a-conffile-prompt-in-unattended-upgrades)

Comment: And also: [What happens with changed config files when unattended-upgrades runs?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1237366/158442)